# Hall current sensor

Tags: sensor

I am measuring current of a 0.83mA with a Hall current sensor ACS273 100mV/A. I want to display this current as 8.3V.
The problem is that in the datasheet of  the ACS273 it is mentioned that no current output is 0.1*VCC=0.5V. at no current I want 0V.
I have used opamp to get 8.3V from the output of ACS. how can I get rid of this extra 0.5V so that it does not get  amplified.
 Ii also presume that no current voltage is added into the further voltages of ACS. i.e.

0.5V    @ 0 Amp

0.5+y V @ x Amp

is it right?[image]

Comment: Provide a link to the data sheet please.

Comment: Datasheet: http://www.allegromicro.com/~/media/Files/Datasheets/ACS723-Datasheet.ashx
This is not a good choice of IC for measuring an 830uA current.  It is unlikely that you will be able to make a measurement. The -05AB version would be a better choice, but it will still be difficult.

Comment: please can you help me in picking an alternative?

Comment: and -AB is bidirectional and will give me 0.5*VCC=2.5V zero current output voltage

Comment: Do you have to use a hall sensor? Why not use a shunt resistor and differential amplifier? A hall sensor capable of reading small currents will be expensive.

Comment: can u elaborate it? by a block diagram

Comment: Get a 0.5V reference and use an op-amp subtractor, your circuit will cost more however.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the main reason why your requirements are fairly pointless: -

[image]

Using the blue (nominal curve), a temperature drift from 15 degC to 50 degC takes the offset voltage from about 497 mV to about 499 mV - that's approximately 2 mV per 35 degC or 57 uV per degC.

And your signal is sitting on that drift with a value of 83 uV.

Comment: is there any alternative to measure this current?

Comment: Basically you need a hall sensor that has a higher sensitivity. Trying to measure 850 uA in a full scale of 40 amps is problematic.

Comment: if i use -10AU its uni directional and its graph is quite stable.. will you recommend this ic?

Comment: Well, if you look at the graph in the data sheet what sort of drift problems does it cause. In other words, repeat what I did and ask yourself the question, if the ambient temperature moved 5 degC, will the effect of that swamp my signal?

Comment: is there any other way to do this task?

Comment: All I know is that you want to measure 0.83 mA using a hall effect sensor. I only have the detail in this question to go-on. You have chosen a hall-effect device because it works with dc signals and isolates and, assuming that is important to you then look for a more sensitive hall sensor. You could start feeding my all sorts of details about your requirements and the bandwidth of the signal etc but this is not a free design service. I regard my part in this question as closed and maybe you should and formally accept the answer.....

Comment: .... If you want to open a new question where you go into more details about what signal you are trying to measure and to what accuracy then this is probably your best option. If you do this, put a link in that new question back to this saying "it is related".